# How to avoid IAM dependencies preventing CFT delete when a role is referenced by an IAM Profile and EC2 Policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a CFT that has these 5 resources:

```
MasterAsg:
  Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
  Properties:
    ...
    LaunchConfigurationName:
      Ref: MasterLaunchConfig
MasterLaunchConfig:
  Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
  Properties:
    ...
    IamInstanceProfile:
      Ref: MasterIntanceProfile
MasterIntanceProfile:
  Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
  Properties:
    Roles:
      - Ref: MasterIamRole
MasterIamRole:
  Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  Properties:
    ...
MasterIamPolicy:
  Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
  Properties:
    Roles:
      - Ref: MasterIamRole
    ...
```

Below is a drawing of how these are dependent on each other.

[image: Dependency graph of CFT resources]

I've had some cases where a different part of this CFT fails and causes the stack to roll back. Below is the error I get:

```
[MasterIamRole] Cannot delete entity, must detach all policies first. (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 409; Error Code: DeleteConflict
```

How can I either change how these resources are created or add the right DependsOn attribute to this stack to prevent running into this in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wound up attaching the policy to the role directly as shown in this example:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html#aws-resource-iam-role-example1.yaml